# UDF в Excel. Составление формулы. Ограничение длины

Tags: excel

Помогите записать формулу через `UDF` в `Excel`. Формула очень длинная получается, а в `Excel` стоит ограничение на длину формулы.

Сама формула:

```
= (1-Константы!$B$1)+Константы!$B$1*
  (СУММ(ЕСЛИ(Связи!C$2>0,$B2/Связи!$BPE$2,0),
  ЕСЛИ(Связи!C$3>0,$C2/Связи!$BPE$3,0),
  ЕСЛИ(Связи!C$4>0,$D2/Связи!$BPE$4,0),
  ЕСЛИ(Связи!C$5>0,$E2/Связи!$BPE$5,0),
  ЕСЛИ(Связи!C$6>0,$F2/Связи!$BPE$6,0),
  ЕСЛИ(Связи!C$7>0,$G2/Связи!$BPE$7,0),
  ЕСЛИ(Связи!C$8>0,$H2/Связи!$BPE$8,0),
  ЕСЛИ(Связи!C$9>0,$I2/Связи!$BPE$9,0),
  ЕСЛИ(Связи!C$10>0,$J2/Связи!$BPE$10,0),
  ЕСЛИ(Связи!C$11>0,$K2/Связи!$BPE$11,0),
  ЕСЛИ(Связи!C$12>0,$L2/Связи!$BPE$12,0),
  ЕСЛИ(Связи!C$13>0,$M2/Связи!$BPE$13,0)))
```

Comment: разбейте формулу на несколько ячеек

Comment: Используй формулы для массивов. Не помню как. Но очень похоже, что они тут идеально подойдут.

Comment: Попробовал переделать в массив, получаются другие значения. 
=(1-$C$14)+$C$14*(СУММ(ЕСЛИ(C$21:C$32>0,$C35:$N35/$P$21:$P$32,0)))

Comment: Оригинальная формула:
=(1-$C$14)+$C$14*(СУММ(ЕСЛИ(C$21>0,$C35/$P$21,0),ЕСЛИ(C$22>0,$D35/$P$22,0),ЕСЛИ(C$23>0,$E35/$P$23,0),ЕСЛИ(C$24>0,$F35/$P$24,0),ЕСЛИ(C$25>0,$G35/$P$25,0),ЕСЛИ(C$26>0,$H35/$P$26,0),ЕСЛИ(C$27>0,$I35/$P$27,0),ЕСЛИ(C$28>0,$J35/$P$28,0),ЕСЛИ(C$29>0,$K35/$P$29,0),ЕСЛИ(C$30>0,$L35/$P$30,0),ЕСЛИ(C$31>0,$M35/$P$31,0),ЕСЛИ(C$32>0,$N35/$P$32,0)))